# Raw sockets permission IPhone?

Tags: iphone, sockets

I'm discovering capability of Iphone network programing. I have already working ICMP ECHO REQUEST / REPLAY using SOCK_DGRAM. And I would like to do more stuffs. For example port scan in NMap. Yes, I can use TCP connect(). But I wanna try to send TCP SYN. 
My question is, can use raw sockets ? Because Iphone doesn't have root permission. And Unix Os need permission to use raw socket. But I found somewhere, that I can use SOCK_RAW and build own IP Header. Allows this Apple ? 
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that inside the SDK. If you are building a jailbreak app you can do this without any problem, probably you will need some headers, including the UDP header and possibly some BPF if you want to sniff packets (like tcpdump, which you can find a iPhone version on Saurik's repository) that are not present on the SDK. You can just copy them from Mac OS X (/usr/include) and put them on /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/ for example.